# PHP - $_POST SQL query not updating column with correct value(s)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've labeled the query that doesn't work in the code below.

What's weird to me is that the query is setting these columns to 0 when the values in the query are being echoed after.

I tried combing everything into one query, I tried running the queries out of the loop.

I hope I'm making sense, I've tried commenting the code below for better understanding.

```
   if (isset($_POST['return'])) {
        $hero = DB::query('SELECT * FROM ownedheroes WHERE id=:id', array(':id' => $_POST['return']));

        // Set isTraining to 0 - WORKS
        DB::query('UPDATE ownedheroes SET isTraining=:isTraining WHERE id=:id', array(':isTraining' => 0, 
        ':id' => $hero[0]['id']));

        $currentLevel = $hero[0]['level']; // Outputs 1
        $levelsToAdd = 0;
        $expToLevel = $levelsToAdd + $currentLevel * 100; // Outputs 100
        $trainingExp = $hero[0]['training_exp']; // Outputs 133

        while ($trainingExp > 0) {
            if ($trainingExp >= $expToLevel) {
                $trainingExp -= $expToLevel;
                $levelsToAdd++;
                continue;
            } else {
                // Doesn't work
                DB::query('UPDATE ownedheroes SET level=:level AND exp=:exp WHERE id=:id', array(
                    ':level' => $currentLevel + $levelsToAdd, // Sets column to 0
                    ':exp' => $trainingExp, // Sets column to 0
                    ':id' => $hero[0]['id'] // Works
                ));

                echo $levelsToAdd + "<be>"; // Echos 1
                echo $currentLevel + $levelsToAdd; // Echos 2
                echo $trainingExp; // Echos 33
                echo 'done';
                
                // Works
                DB::query('UPDATE ownedheroes SET training_exp=:training_exp WHERE id=:id', array(
                    ':training_exp' => 0,
                    ':id' => $hero[0]['id']
                ));

                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

SQL that created the table

```
CREATE TABLE `ownedheroes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `owner` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `rarity` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `level` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `exp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `isTraining` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `training_exp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `power_level` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `ownedheroes`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=52;
ALTER TABLE `ownedheroes`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

$hero output

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [0] => 1 [name] => Nishio [1] => Nishio [owner] => Tyler [2] => Tyler [rarity] => COMMON [3] => COMMON [level] => 1 [4] => 1 [exp] => 0 [5] => 0 [isTraining] => 1 [6] => 1 [training_exp] => 136 [7] => 136 [power_level] => 42 [8] => 42 ) )
```

DB::query function

```
        public static function query($query, $params = array()) {
                $statement = self::connect()->prepare($query);
                $statement->execute($params);

                if (explode(' ', $query)[0] == 'SELECT') {
                $data = $statement->fetchAll();
                return $data;
                }
        }
```

Comment: Can you show the sql that created the table? Im curious to see how those 2 columns are defined

Comment: @WesleySmith

`
CREATE TABLE `ownedheroes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `owner` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `rarity` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `level` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `exp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `isTraining` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `training_exp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `power_level` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
`

Comment: For some reason, it's not showing it @Strawberry, but I do have it set as an auto-incrementing primary key.

Comment: @Strawberry The end of my SQL file has it

ALTER TABLE `ownedheroes`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=52;

ALTER TABLE `ownedheroes`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

Comment: Please add the `$hearo` output from the first query

Comment: @BasheerKharoti Added

Comment: Your output is still quite vague as the values are repeated for two different indexes. Can you add the `DB::query` method to see how you execute that

Comment: @BasheerKharoti Added